# Angular 8 - How to add multiple same-name query parameters in Angular HttpParams

Tags: http, parameters, angular8

I already test this code

```
let params = new HttpParams();

params.append('someParmName', 'value1');
params.append('someParmName', 'value2');
```

I would like this type of url on a **method GET** to send for the backend

url: ?someParmName=value1&someParmName=value2

But i have this:
?someParmName=value1
http.get();

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
params = {someParmName: ['value1', 'value2']};
http.get('...', {params})
```